# React Native Firebase push notification not working when App is in background or closed

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have an App with android/ios and I implemented push notification with react-native-firebase.

On android I am receiving notifications either app is in foreground/background as documentation.

On ios version of app I can receive notification when app is in foreground, But when app is in background or close no notification received.

```
"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9",
```

I am testing with https://console.firebase.google.com and http://pushtry.com/

I am struggling last couple of days.

Comment: Did you use `notification Listener` ?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes, I used 'onMessage' and 'onNotification' listeners

Comment: @RazaHussain is this issue got resolved?

Comment: @RazaHussain is it fixed???

Comment: @SharadPawar I resolved it. I am sending remote message from server then catch it in "onMessage" callback.